# kotlinx.serialization: inject local parameter

Tags: kotlin, serialization, dependency-injection, kotlinx.serialization

I need to **inject a local value to a class constructor during deserialization**. For example, look at the following class.

```kotlin
@Serializable
class SomeClass(val local: Context, val serialized: String)
```

I want the field `local` to be skipped during serialization and substituted with some predefined local value during deserialization.

The reason behind is that I'm going to transfer models through network, but operations on these models rely on a local context which I want to inject.

Because I haven't find any standard ways to achieve it, I've decided to make use of contextual serialization. So I have written the serializer:

```kotlin
class ContextualInjectorSerializer<T>(private val localValue: T) : KSerializer<T> {
    override val descriptor = SerialDescriptor("ValueInjection", StructureKind.OBJECT)

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): T {
        decoder.beginStructure(descriptor).endStructure(descriptor)
        return localValue
    }

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: T) {
        encoder.beginStructure(descriptor).endStructure(descriptor)
    }
}
```

And used it this way:

```kotlin
// Context is marked with @Serializable(with = ContextSerializer::class)

val json = Json(JsonConfiguration.Stable, SerializersModule {
     contextual(Context::class, ContextualInjectorSerializer(context))
})
// serialize/deserialize
```

Surprisingly, it works pretty fine on JVM. However, when I compiled it to JS and tested, I got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'siteId' of undefined`. Here `siteId` is a field of Context which I try to access.

Is there a standard way to inject local parameters? What's wrong with my trick?